# Assingment from char[] disappears once original variable is reset

Tags: c

I am trying to make an application similar to the Ubuntu terminal in C. It supports the commands touch, ls, and clear (to some extent). (in the run function) When I use the touch command to make a file, the command is parsed and the name is put in the new_thing char[]. It assigns the file_name to new_thing. After every command I reset the variable new_thing using memset. When I use the ls command however, the name is blank and I don't know why.

I tried changing how I reset the variable, but it didn't help. From what I can see, whatever I set new_thing to be, every file_name is set to new_thing even though I set every file once. The code is down below.

main.c

```c
    #include "file_explorer.h"
    
    int main(void)
    {
      run();
      return 0;
    }
```

file_explorer.h

```c
    #ifndef FILE_EXPLORER_H_
    #define FILE_EXPLORER_H_
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    #define READ_PERMISSIONS    0x04
    #define WRITE_PERMISSIONS   0x02
    #define EXECUTE_PERMISSIONS 0x01
    #define ADMIN_PERMISSIONS   0x07
    #define LS_COMMAND    "ls"
    #define CD_COMMAND    "cd"
    #define PWD_COMMAND   "pwd"
    #define MKDIR_COMMAND "mkdir"
    #define TOUCH_COMMAND "touch"
    
    typedef struct File File;
    typedef struct Folder Folder;
    
    struct File {
      char *file_name;
      char *file_path;
      uint8_t file_permissions;
      char *contents;
    };

    struct Folder {
      char *folder_name;
      char *folder_path;
      File files[5];
      Folder *folders[2];
    };

    File new_file( char * , uint8_t );
    char *add_contents(char * );
    Folder new_folder( char * );
    void change_directory(char * );
    void print_file(char * );
    void run();
    
    #endif
```

file_explorer.c

```c
    #include "file_explorer.h"
    
    char current_path[100] = "";
    char input[100] = "";
    char command[10] = "";
    char new_thing[90] = "";
    Folder home;
    
    File new_file(char *file_name, uint8_t file_permissions)
    {
      File file = {
        .file_name = file_name,
        .file_path = current_path,
        .file_permissions = file_permissions,
        .contents = NULL
      };
      return file;
    }
    
    char * add_contents(char * contents)
    {
      return contents; 
    }
    
    Folder new_folder(char *folder_name)
    {
      Folder folder = {
        .folder_name = folder_name,
        .folder_path = current_path,
        .files = NULL,
        .folders = NULL
      };
      return folder;
    }
    
    void change_directory(char *directory)
    {
      strcat(current_path, "/");
      strcat(current_path, directory);
    }
    
    void print_file(char *contents)
    {
      if (contents == NULL)
      {
        printf("ERROR: File empty\n");
      } else 
      {
        printf("%s\n", contents);
      }
    }
    
    void run()
    {
      system("clear");
      home = new_folder("home");  
      int counter = 0;
      while (true)
      {
        printf("parker@PARKERMASON%s$ ", current_path);
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
        memset(command,0,strlen(command));
        memset(new_thing,0,strlen(new_thing));
    
        if (input[0] == 't' && input[1] == 'o' && input[2] == 'u' && input[3] == 'c' && input[4] == 'h' && input[5] == ' ')
        {
          int i = strlen(TOUCH_COMMAND) + 1;
          strcpy(command, TOUCH_COMMAND);
           
          for (int j = 0; j < strlen(input) - strlen(TOUCH_COMMAND) - 1; j++)
          {
            new_thing[j] = input[i];
            i++;
          }
          
          if (counter == 0)
          {
            home.files[0] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
            printf("%s\n", home.files[0].file_name);
          } else if (counter == 1)
          {
            home.files[1] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
          } else if (counter == 2)
          {
            home.files[2] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
          } else if (counter == 3)
          {
            home.files[3] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
          } else if (counter ==  4)
          {
            home.files[4] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
          } else
          {
            printf("Folder full\n");
          }
          counter++;
        } else if (input[0] == 'l' && input[1] == 's' && input[2] == '\0')
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(home.files) / sizeof(home.files[0]); j++)
          {
            if (home.files[j].file_name != NULL)
            {
              printf("%s ", home.files[j].file_name);
            } else
            {
              printf("EMPTY ");
            }
          }
        printf("\n"); 
        } else if (input[0] == 'c' && input[1] == 'd' && input[2] == ' ')
        {
          int i = strlen(CD_COMMAND) + 1;
          strcpy(command, CD_COMMAND);
          
          for (int j = 0; j < strlen(input) - strlen(CD_COMMAND) - 1; j++)
          {
            new_thing[j] = input[i];
            i++;
          }
        }
        else if (input[0] == 'c' && input[1] == 'l' && input[2] == 'e' && input[3] == 'a' && input[4] == 'r' && input[5] == '\0')
        {
          system("clear");
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: It is in the works and will have more features implemented

Comment: Its because you are assigning the address of `new_thing` to pointer `file_name`. Make any changes in `new_thing`, it will be reflected in `file_name`. Use `strdup()` or manually allocate memory to `file_name` pointer and copy the content of `new_thing` to that memory.

Comment: As for why ls command is emtpy, I think you have missed a `strcpy(command, LS_COMMAND)` after the if condition checking `ls` characters

Comment: TYSM I could not figure this out and it was making me go insane I really appreciate both of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File new_file(char *file_name, uint8_t file_permissions){
    File file = {
        .file_name = file_name,
    //...
}
```

The above snippet stores the pointer parameter `file_name` to the struct `file`. In particular, it does not copy the original string. That means whenever the buffer pointed to by `file_name` is updated, the string you observe via `file.file_name` is also updated.

You called this function with

```
home.files[0] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
```

Combining with the above, it means `home.files[0].file_name == new_thing` and they point to the beginning of the same string, so it's not surprising when you do

```
memset(new_thing,0,strlen(new_thing));
```

and examine `home.files[0].file_name` later, it is empty.

What you actually want to do is storing a copy of the string in your struct. This can be done by `strdup` if your system supports it.

```
File new_file(char *file_name, uint8_t file_permissions){
    File file = {
        .file_name = strdup(file_name),
    //...
}
```

Note that you need to properly free the memory of `file.file_name` in order to avoid memory leak.

If you don't have `strdup`, you should manually allocate the buffer and copy the string to it.

```
File new_file(char *file_name, uint8_t file_permissions){
    char* file_name_copy = malloc(strlen(file_name)+1);
    if(!file_name_copy){
        //error handling, early return
    }
    strcpy(file_name_copy, file_name);
    File file = {
        .file_name = file_name_copy,
    //...
}
```

Side notes:

```
input[0] == 't' && input[1] == 'o' && input[2] == 'u' && input[3] == 'c' && input[4] == 'h' && input[5] == ' '
```

This is really unnecessarily verbose and should just be `strncmp(input, "touch ", 6)` instead.

```
else if (counter == 1)
{
    home.files[1] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
} else if (counter == 2)
{
    home.files[2] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
}
//...
```

This is just

```
else if(counter < 5){
    home.files[i] = new_file(new_thing, ADMIN_PERMISSIONS);
}
//...
```

Comment: TYSM this really helped (especially with how char *'s work). Thank you for giving such a helpful answer :D